# How can I check the 5 ccspirits have passed through the screen on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have many ccspirits in NSMutableArray, and I am taking them from these NSMutableArray, and sending to as method as a sender, and following

```
   id actionMove2 = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:6 position:ccp(40, 520)];
   id actionMoveDone2 = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished:)];

  [sender runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMove2, actionMoveDone2, nil]];
```

now I want to calculate that five ccspirit has passed through the screen because the user is draging and droping many items so these will not be included, how can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so if you want to subtract out the images that were moved by the user.  I'm assuming you have some code in place in your ccTouchesMoved or Began that checks if the touch is on a sprite and moves it accordingly.  If that's the case I think (havent tested) that you could remove that object from your array by calling

```
[myArray removeObject:sender];
```

Then you could just keep track of how many objects are in there by checking it's count

```
[myArray count];
```

Comment: but dear I have some ccspirite that if user will move, then they will be excluded from, well I am trying to minus them from total ccspirite and if remaing is 5 then I will perform some stuff

Comment: @Veer check the edits and see if that's what you need, I'm still a bit confused on your requirements.